# How to solve the 'undefined reference to libusb' error in ros?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, cmake, ros

I am trying to transfer a camera(non-uvc) stream program to ros platform.

I've already got the camera driver running

and Makefile is like this:

---

```
g++  main.cpp -o test_gui -g  -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib -D_LIN -D_DEBUG   -L../lib/x64 -I../include -lASICamera  -lpthread  -lusb   -DGLIBC_20 -m64 -lrt -I/opt
```

---

Now I want to do this in a ros node, so I write a node in which the CMakelists is like this:

---

```
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
include_directories(/usr/local/include)
include_directories(/root/catkin_ws/src/asi_converter_real/include/asi_converter_real)
link_directories(/usr/local/lib)
link_libraries(pthread)
link_libraries(usb)
link_libraries(libASICamera.a)
link_libraries(libASICamera.so)
add_executable(asi_converter_real src/asi_converter_real.cpp)
target_link_libraries(asi_converter_real ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

And the Makefile line generated into /catkin_ws/build/***/ is like this:

---

```
/usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/asi_converter_real.dir/src/asi_converter_real.cpp.o  -o /root/catkin_ws/devel/lib/asi_converter_real/asi_converter_real -rdynamic -L/usr/local/lib -lpthread -lusb -Wl,-Bstatic -lASICamera -Wl,-Bdynamic -lASICamera
```

---

But it seems that the system cannot find the dynamic libraries of libusb, coz' it reports

---

```
undefined reference to `libusb_set_configuration'
undefined reference to `libusb_claim_interface'
/usr/local/lib/libASICamera.a(ASI174MM.o): In function `WorkingFunc(void*)':
undefined reference to `libusb_bulk_transfer'
undefined reference to `libusb_bulk_transfer'
```

---

[1]Is there anyone who knows how to solve this problem ?

[2]How to find the .a and .so of libusb in my computer ? (I am sure I have them, coz' I can pkg-config --cflags/--libs them)

[3]How could I explicitly link a dynamic library in ros CMakelists ? or just link_libraries(usb) is enough for both static and dynamic libriries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_package` requires that CMake have a corresponding `Find<package>.cmake`

Cmake have a [pkg-config module](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPkgConfig.html).

You can use it to write your own FindLibUSB, [as explained on the CMake wiki](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries#Piggybacking_on_pkg-config).

Or you can use it directly in your CMakeLists.txt :

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(LIBUSB1 REQUIRED libusb-1.0)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${LIBUSB1_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

You can see in [the module documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPkgConfig.html) all the variables that are set : `LIBUSB1_LIBRARIES` for the libraries, etc ...

Answer (score 1):

Finding libraries in cmake is typically done using `find_package`.

In your case it might look like this (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020231/trouble-linking-libusb-using-cmake)):

```
find_package(libusb-1.0 REQUIRED)
include_directories (${LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...
target_link_libraries(asi_converter_real ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${LIBUSB_1_LIBRARIES})
```

You may have to adjust the version number of course (maybe it can simply be removed).

Comment: hi luator, are you still there ? I think my system cannot find this package, it report :(find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package libusb-1.0.

  Set libusb-1.0_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for libusb-1.0.  The file will have one of the following names:

    libusb-1.0Config.cmake
    libusb-1.0-config.cmake

Comment: And I don't think my system have these two variables ${LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIRS} and ${LIBUSB_1_LIBRARIES}, I type apt-get install libusb-1.0 and it just says I've already installed this. Yet, I don't where libusb is. It's not in /usr/lib /usb/bin or /usr/local/lib . Could I locate this package exactly and use the absolute route ?

Comment: @ThuVlion The variables are automatically set if find_package is successful. The error message indicates that you need a `Find<package>.cmake` as described in the other answer. In case you have this problem with other libraries in the future: In most cases you can find a appropriate find-file by simply asking google for "Find<package>.cmake"